# Terraform: How to config null_resource with murtiply connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Suppose that the ec2 module has two server, dynamic created. Like:

```
    module "ec2-web" {
        source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
        version = "4.1.4"
        count = 2
        name = "${local.appName}-webserver-${count.index + 1}"
        .....
    }
```

Now I have a null_resource config file, which has a connection only:

```
        resource "null_resource" "web-upload" {
          depends_on = [module.ec2-web]

          connection {
            type        = "ssh"
            host        = module.ec2-web[0].public_ip
            user        = "ec2-user"
            password    = ""
            private_key = file("keypair/a-ssh-key.pem")
            timeout     = "2m"
          }

          provisioner "remote-exec" {
            inline = [
              "sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html",
              "sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/html",
            ]
          }

          provisioner "file" {
            source      = "web/"
            destination = "/var/www/html"
          }
        }
```

Now how should I update any config can let finally terraform upload files to both server accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the same approach with the `count` meta-argument:

```
resource "null_resource" "web-upload" {
  count = 2

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = module.ec2-web[count.index].public_ip
    user        = "ec2-user"
    password    = ""
    private_key = file("keypair/a-ssh-key.pem")
    timeout     = "2m"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html",
      "sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/html",
    ]
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "web/"
    destination = "/var/www/html"
  }
}
```

The explicit dependency using `depends_on` meta-argument is not required as the reference to the module output is used (`module.ec2-web[count.index].public_ip`). This means terraform will wait for the module to be done with creating resources prior to attempting the `null_resource`.